# Q: Azure service bus specific message handler

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm new to Azure Service Bus or any service bus really.

Is there a way with ASB to create a message and configure it like this so only 1 specific 'handler' can process the message? Preferably without creating new queue's or topics.

I'm going to create an export application, which should create a 'default' message. That can be processed by any handler. But whenever I want/configure, it should be able to create a 'special' message, that just can be handled by a 'special' configured handler.

Comment: _"Preferably without creating new queue's or topics."_ does that mean you already have a topology I place you cannot change? What does it look like?

Comment: No, I don't have anything yet. Just the thoughts how I think it should be build. But after some more research I think topics is a must have in this case. I didn't know about the filtering towards subscriptions, so that makes it fit more into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two Subscriptions for the Topic. Remove the $Default rule/filter on both and then add a custom rule to distinguish between the 'default' and 'special' messages.

I don't know if you already have any way to do this - you can use the message system properties, for instance, if there is one that you can rely on. If not add a custom property to either both types of message or just the 'special' ones and configure the rules accordingly, e.g.

```
MessageType = 'Special'
```

Then configure the handlers to connect to the appropriate Subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you. I think I know what you mean and I've done some more research and just learned about the filters and such. So I think I know enough for now.

Comment: Excellent! Good luck.